# Initialize and access a nested struct char pointer within another struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, char

My issue is in the initialization of the nested struct and then adding to that struct.  I don't know how to properly access the struct to even try to initialize it.  I can initialize the first struct char pointers with malloc, but when I try to initialize the nested struct in such a manner where I can access it with:

```
Rooms[i].Connected[i].conncet_room.
```

There is a break down and my usual error is:

> subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

Which is this line of code:

```
Rooms[i].Connected[j].connect_room=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
typedef struct Connections
{
    char* connect_room; 
} Connections;

typedef struct ROOM
{
   char*  name;
   char*  event;
   int connect_id;
   Connections Connected;
} ROOM;


main(){
    // creates memory space for 6 rooms.
    int sizeOf=6; 
    ROOM* Rooms = malloc(sizeOf*sizeof *Rooms);

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<sizeOf;i++)
    {
        Rooms[i].name=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
        Rooms[i].event=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
        for(j=0;j<sizeOf,j++)
            Rooms[i].Connected[j].connect_room=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    }
}

strcpy( Rooms[0].name, "kitchen"); // This works
strcpy( Rooms[0].Connected[0].connect_room, "hallway"); // This doesn't works
strcpy( Rooms[0].Connected[1].connect_room, "deck"); // This doesn't works
```

Essential I would like the struct to be structured like so: (The following is meant to be an example of the struct layout and not code)

```
 Rooms[0]
     name --> "bed_room"
     event --> "sleep"
     Connected[0]
         connection_room --> "bath_room"
     ...
     Connected[5]
         connection_room --> "hall_way"
```

Each Room would have a name and an event, then it would have 1-6 connection_rooms.

Finally, once the nested struct is successfully initialized. How would I add to .connect_room?

```
strcpy(Rooms[0].Connected[0].connect_room, "bath_room");
```

I'm compiling with gcc

Comment: In `ROOM` you have `Connections Connected` which is not an array, so when you access `Connected` as an array it gives you an error.

Comment: You should access the `Connected` member as `Rooms[i].Connected.connect_room`. It is not dynamically allocated, nor an array. You have one `Connected ` per room.

Comment: @ericbn I have been able to access it that way.  I was trying to setup a nested array. Where one room could have many connections.

Comment: `... .connect_room=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)`  is strange.  `connect_room` is a pointer to `char`.  `malloc(sizeof(char*))` allocates the size of the pointer, not the size of the array of `char` it points to.

Comment: @chux Maybe I was way off mark. I was at the point where I was trying anything to make it work...

Comment: @jkramerjj, I suggest you study more on C memory allocation, and arrays (the string being a char array).

Comment: What do you expect this `...=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have a fixed number of rooms, which you initialise at run time. There appears also to be a maximum of connections for each room.  In that case, you don't have to `malloc` anything. Define an array and let the connections be pointers into that array.

C isn't good at handling and looking up strings. (Okay, it can be made good, but string handling is somewhat cumbersome.) So let's not make the Room connections strings, but pointers to other rooms:

```
typedef struct Room Room;

#define MAX_CONN 6

struct Room {
   char *name;
   char *event;
   Room *conn[MAX_CONN];    // Connected rooms or NULL
};
```

The connections are an array of at most `MAX_CONN` pointers to other rooms. Unused slots are `NULL`. (You could even make the connections directed, so that the six slots refer to exits to the north, east, south and west, upstairs and downstairs.)

Since I've advised against using strings as means of identification, we will use the ordinal numbers of the room array entry. Bare numbers are a bit unintuitive, so let's declare a list of enumerated values:

```
enum {
    Hallway,
    Bathroom,
    Bedroom,
    NRooms
};
```

This declares the room names as constants 0, 1 and 2 and `NRooms` is the number of rooms, 3.

Now the room array declaration:

```
int main()
{
    Room rooms[NRooms] = {
        [Hallway] = {
            .name = "Hallway", 
            .event = "loiter",
            .conn = {
                rooms + Bedroom,
                rooms + Bathroom
            }
        },
        [Bedroom] = {
            .name = "Bedroom", 
            .event = "sleep",
            .conn = {
                rooms + Hallway
            }

        },
        [Bathroom] = {
            .name = "Bathroom", 
            .event = "wash",
            .conn = {
                rooms + Hallway
            }

        }
    };

    room_print(&rooms[Hallway]);    // or: rooms + Hallway
    room_print(&rooms[Bedroom]);
    room_print(&rooms[Bathroom]);

    return 0;
}
```

The array is initialised. I've used [designated initialisers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) here, a C99 feature that allows you to specify the array indices and struct member names explicitly. It's a bit of an overkill here, but it might be handy if you create more rooms and add more stuff to your room struct. (In this example, everything is initialised in order, so you could omit the desigtnated initialisers and just use traditional positional initialisation.)

The notation `rooms + x` uses [pointer arithmetic](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html) to create a pointer to element `x` in the `rooms` array. The expression is equivalent to `&rooms[x]`.

Array elements and struct elements that aren't explicitly initialised are initialised to a zero or null value. For pointers, that is `NULL`.

Finally, the `room_print` routine to put the created data structure into practice:

```
void room_print(const Room *room)
{
    int i;

    printf("This is the %s where you %s.\n",
        room->name, room->event);

    i = 0;
    while (i < MAX_CONN && room->conn[i]) {
        printf("A door leads to the %s.\n",
            room->conn[i]->name);
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Sorry to be a bit verbose, since you asked only about how to access the connections, but I think the example shows how something like your example layout for the struct can be acheved with C initialisers.

The data can still be changed at run-time, of course. Nothing stops you from saying:

```
room[Bathroom].name = "Private bathroom";
room[Bathroom].conn[1] = Bedroom;
room[Bedroom].conn[1] = Bathroom;
```

Comment: I like this way of accessing and manipulating the structs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want each room to have 1-6 `Connections` items, you need to change your `ROOM` declaration. You can do that with static or dynamic allocation.

#### Static allocation

```
typedef struct ROOM
{
    char* name;
    char* event;
    int connect_id;
    Connections Connected[6];
} ROOM;

// Don't need code to dynamically allocate Connected
for (j = 0; j < 6, j++) {
    // 256 is max size of connect_room string
    Rooms[i].Connected[j].connect_room = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
}
```

You wouldn't need to dynamically allocate the `connect_room` variable if you had:

```
typedef struct Connections 
{
    char connect_room[256]; 
} Connections;
```

You can also do that with the `name` and `event` members of `ROOM`.

Maybe you should stick with static allocation before getting more used to dynamic allocation. You will have to mind freeing all the memory you allocated dynamically.

#### Dynamic allocation

```
typedef struct ROOM
{
    char* name;
    char* event;
    int connect_id;
    Connections* Connected;
} ROOM;

// To dynamically allocate Connected for each room:
Rooms[i].Connected = malloc(sizeof(Connections)*6);
for (j = 0; j < 6, j++) {
    // 256 is max size of connect_room string
    Rooms[i].Connected[j].connect_room = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
}
```

Comment: I worry about the latest generation of potential engineers growing up in a world with websites like this one where you can go from 1. question to 2. code snippet within seconds.

Comment: @tgm1024, I feel the same. We didn't even had BBSs when I started...  ;- )

Comment: I hate to make it sound like "Jeez, kids today....", but it really is true.  Back in the early 80's, if you couldn't figure out an algorithm yourself, and if you weren't lucky enough to have it in a Knuth book, you really had to claw your way through it.  And we were all the better for it. I used to lament that there was no *real* (you know what I mean) internet when I went to college and high school. Now I'm SO thankful there wasn't. That and the machines today are so frighteningly powerful that there's never anything akin to the fight involved in geting a square root routine in 6502 to work.

Comment: @tgm1024 maybe your grandfather felt the same way about your generation with his abacus :)  Kids these days with their calculators, in my day we did it all by hand!   I appreciate having access to such a wealth a knowledge, this newer generation is very lucky to have access to such expertise so quickly!

Comment: @jkramerjj: Hmhm ... I am not so sure if fast access to any knowledge/solutions really is (only) an improvement. It is very handy to be capable to "chew" on an issue. And this certainly needs to be trained, and to do so one needs time, much time ... - be sure this one issue gets you one day: no references on gxxgle, no answers on SO. Then you need to "chew", "bite"... ;-)

Comment: @jkramerjj, that theory only works if the problems scale with the ability to solve them, and they don't.  It's precisely as alk said: it's the relentless (and sometimes painful) munching on a problem over days that produces the TRUE growth.  Everything else is far too close to cut and paste.  Your analogy is flawed.

Comment: @ericbn Thanks a lot! Works like a champ.

Comment: @ericbn It definitely helped, however I am unable to up vote, because my rep is not high enough.. I will certainly come back and up-vote once I am able.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
...
Connections * Connected;
...
```